# Positioning menu with bigSlide jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am having trouble positioning the menu with the bigSlide jquery plugin created by Adam Scott. The clickable link (wrap class) does respond to css but alas the menu (panel class) does not. So the clickable link is the specified 100 px from the bottom of the page but alas the menu (which slides OK) is still at the top of the page. I feel there is a straight forward solution to this but it currently escapes me.

The code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Big Slide Menu</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.big-slide.js"></script>
    <script>    
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.menu-link').bigSlide({});
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        .panel {
            position:   absolute;
            bottom:     180px;
            left:       -15.625em; 
            width:      15.625em;   
        }
        .wrap {
            position:   absolute;
            bottom:     100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav id="menu" class="panel" role="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">The Ballad of El Goodo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Thirteen</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">September Gurls</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">What's Going Ahn</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="wrap">
        <a href="#menu" class="menu-link">&#9776;</a>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of things, `bigSlide.js` adds default inline styles to your `nav.panel`, which override your styles.

```
/* Added by bigSlide.js */
element.style {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    /* etc... */
}
```

They don't seem to offer [options](http://ascott1.github.io/bigSlide.js/#options) to handle what you want, and you most certainly don't want to override the default library JS or the CSS on the element by forcing styles with `!important`.

If we think about it logically, the styles they add actually make sense, we want the panel to be fixed from top to bottom, regardless of what HTML it contains.

So in your case, I suggest you add custom styling to the `<ul>` element.

```
.panel ul {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 150px; /* Or whatever you want */
    left:0;
}
```

Let me know if this doesn't make sense.

```js
/*! bigSlide - v0.8.0 - 2015-04-28
* http://ascott1.github.io/bigSlide.js/
* Copyright (c) 2015 Adam D. Scott; Licensed MIT */
!function(a){"use strict";"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["jquery"],a):"object"==typeof exports?module.exports=a(require("jquery")):a(jQuery)}(function(a){"use strict";a.fn.bigSlide=function(b){var c=this,d=a.extend({menu:"#menu",push:".push",side:"left",menuWidth:"15.625em",speed:"300",state:"closed",activeBtn:"active",easyClose:!1,beforeOpen:function(){},afterOpen:function(){},beforeClose:function(){},afterClose:function(){}},b),e={state:d.state},f={init:function(){g.init()},changeState:function(){"closed"===e.state?e.state="open":e.state="closed"},getState:function(){return e.state}},g={init:function(){this.$menu=a(d.menu),this.$push=a(d.push),this.width=d.menuWidth;var b={position:"fixed",top:"0",bottom:"0",height:"100%"};b[d.side]="-"+d.menuWidth,b.width=d.menuWidth,"closed"===d.state&&(this.$menu.css(b),this.$push.css(d.side,"0"));var e={"-webkit-transition":d.side+" "+d.speed+"ms ease","-moz-transition":d.side+" "+d.speed+"ms ease","-ms-transition":d.side+" "+d.speed+"ms ease","-o-transition":d.side+" "+d.speed+"ms ease",transition:d.side+" "+d.speed+"ms ease"};this.$menu.css(e),this.$push.css(e),c.on("click.bigSlide touchstart.bigSlide",function(a){a.preventDefault(),"open"===f.getState()?g.toggleClose():g.toggleOpen()}),d.easyClose&&a("body").on("click.bigSlide",function(b){a(b.target).parents().andSelf().is(c)||"open"!==f.getState()||g.toggleClose()})},toggleOpen:function(){d.beforeOpen(),f.changeState(),this.$menu.css(d.side,"0"),this.$push.css(d.side,this.width),c.addClass(d.activeBtn),d.afterOpen()},toggleClose:function(){d.beforeClose(),f.changeState(),this.$menu.css(d.side,"-"+this.width),this.$push.css(d.side,"0"),c.removeClass(d.activeBtn),d.afterClose()}};f.init()}});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu-link').bigSlide();
});
```

```css
.panel {
  position: absolute;
  /*bottom: 180px;*/ /*not going to make a difference because it's overwritten */
  left: -15.625em;
  width: 15.625em;
}
.panel ul {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150px;
  left: 0;
}
.wrap {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="menu" class="panel" role="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">The Ballad of El Goodo</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Thirteen</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">September Gurls</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">What's Going Ahn</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="wrap">
  <a href="#menu" class="menu-link">&#9776;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Your suggestion was a good one - styling the <ul> element works. It looks as though you were spot on with the .panel styling being overridden. Thanks.

Comment: My pleasure :) If my answer has helped you fix your solution completely please mark it as so :)